# Google Custom search JSON API not returning all the results

Tags: json, google-custom-search

I am using the Google custom search api for site -"yeskantipur.com". When I search for the term "site:yeskantipur.com Sony Xperia Sola" on Google search I get a lot of results. But with the API, I get only two results. The result in first position in normal search is not returned by Custom Search. Instead the second result is shown..

Here is the items of output json:

```
    "items": [
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Virgin Mobile",
   "htmlTitle": "Virgin Mobile",
   "link": "http://www.yeskantipur.com/index.php?route=product/vendor&vendor_id=57",
   "displayLink": "www.yeskantipur.com",
   "snippet": "SONY XPERIA SOLA. GENERAL 2G Network G.. ... Also known as Sony Ericsson   Xperia Nozomi, Sony Ericsson Arc HD .. 40000.00. Ex Tax: Rs.40,000.00 ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eSONY XPERIA SOLA\u003c/b\u003e. GENERAL 2G Network G.. \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e Also known as Sony Ericsson \u003cbr\u003e  Xperia Nozomi, Sony Ericsson Arc HD .. 40000.00. Ex Tax: Rs.40,000.00 \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "Zm5BwsKSGxcJ",
   "formattedUrl": "www.yeskantipur.com/index.php?route=product/vendor...id...",
   "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.yeskantipur.com/index.php?route=product/vendor...id...",
   "pagemap": {
    "cse_image": [
     {
      "src": "http://www.yeskantipur.com/image/cache/data/virgin/sony-x8-182x182.jpg"
     }
    ],
    "cse_thumbnail": [
     {
      "width": "145",
      "height": "145",
      "src": "https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRh7wPGludHnxspronMl2eITUvTqYjUZ0-KSOgDsiVyvywyCVnYT09KpP8"
     }
    ]
   }
  },
  {
   "kind": "customsearch#result",
   "title": "Sony Ericsson",
   "htmlTitle": "\u003cb\u003eSony\u003c/b\u003e Ericsson",
   "link": "http://www.yeskantipur.com/index.php?route=product/category&path=106",
   "displayLink": "www.yeskantipur.com",
   "snippet": "Sony Xperia Neo L. Also known as Sony MT25i. .. Rs.23,500.00. Ex Tax: Rs.  23,500.00. Add to Bag. Add to Wish List. Add to Compare. Sony Xperai Sola ...",
   "htmlSnippet": "\u003cb\u003eSony Xperia\u003c/b\u003e Neo L. Also known as \u003cb\u003eSony\u003c/b\u003e MT25i. .. Rs.23,500.00. Ex Tax: Rs.\u003cbr\u003e  23,500.00. Add to Bag. Add to Wish List. Add to Compare. \u003cb\u003eSony\u003c/b\u003e Xperai \u003cb\u003eSola\u003c/b\u003e \u003cb\u003e...\u003c/b\u003e",
   "cacheId": "k_N9tKXWitYJ",
   "formattedUrl": "www.yeskantipur.com/index.php?route=product/category&path...",
   "htmlFormattedUrl": "www.yeskantipur.com/index.php?route=product/category&amp;path...",
   "pagemap": {
    "cse_image": [
     {
      "src": "http://www.yeskantipur.com/image/cache/data/ctv-mobile/1-180x180.jpg"
     }
    ],
    "cse_thumbnail": [
     {
      "width": "144",
      "height": "144",
      "src": "https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRkJbvtpWJeEFS4E9sCXi-tvnFa-20T3YOzF6v6UDhDNYBpep1TWhoaSYMM"
     }
    ]
```

Comment: I think custom search show only ads link not all... so this happen

Comment: @nKandel Custom search will not show ads. Its different from adsense's custom search.

Comment: The results might be different in google where the search is associated with your profile.  If you search in a private browsing window without signing in, do you get the same results?